# Attempt to get an object - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
    const scheduleMessageSchema = new Schema({
        guildId: Number,
        setting: {
        logs: Boolean,
        deleteCH: Boolean,
        updateCH: Boolean,
        voiceupdateState: Boolean,
        memberaddServer: Boolean,
      }
});
```

I have a diagram of this type. You need to get the value of the logs object.
I tried to do it like this - `server.setting[logs]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const scheduleMessageSchema = new Schema({
        guildId: Number,
        setting: {
        logs: Boolean,
        deleteCH: Boolean,
        updateCH: Boolean,
        voiceupdateState: Boolean,
        memberaddServer: Boolean,
      }
});
```

to access logs, use => server.setting.logs

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'logs' of undefined

Comment: what is server here? There might be some issue with server. Try to print server